# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when setting strings

Tags: java, mysql

I have a strange problem. When I execute the query in the following piece of code it throws a MySQLSyntaxErrorException with the message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''fantasy' SET Quantity = 3 WHERE BookName = 'The Silmarilion'' at line 1
```

Code:

```
private void updateDBTable(String category, Vector dataVector) {
    try {  
        for(int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {

            String bookName = String.valueOf(((Vector) dataVector.elementAt(i))
                                  .elementAt(0));
            int quantity = (int) ((Vector) dataVector.elementAt(i))
                                  .elementAt(4);               

            statement = databaseConnection
              .prepareStatement("UPDATE ? SET Quantity = ? WHERE BookName = ?");   
            statement.setString(1, category);
            statement.setInt(2, quantity);
            statement.setString(3, bookName);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
```

But if I write it in this way :

```
private void updateDBTable(String category, Vector dataVector) {
    try {  
        for(int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {

            String bookName = String.valueOf(((Vector) dataVector.elementAt(i))
                                        .elementAt(0));
            bookName = "'" + bookName + "'";
            int quantity = (int) ((Vector) dataVector.elementAt(i))
                                        .elementAt(4);               

            statement = databaseConnection
               .prepareStatement("UPDATE " + 
                                  category + 
                                 " SET Quantity = ? WHERE BookName = " + 
                                 bookName);   
            statement.setInt(1, quantity);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
```

It works fine. Can you help me to figure out why the syntax in the first example is wrong?

Comment: You are supplying table name as a parameter, prepared statements will only work for column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you have also provided the table name as a parameter. Prepared statements take the column names as parameters. You need to provide the table name in the statement while using prepareStatement